# Is there a specific way to remove unused pip packages in global environment SAFELY?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, site-packages

I messed up my global environment today.

Today I'm creating a virtual environment called `chatgpt-retrieval` in a folder called `GitOpenSourceApps`

The old directory structure is: `~/GitOpenSourceApps/chatgpt-retrieval` (1)

But then I want to move the virtual environment folder inside another folder called `chatgpt-custom-data` manually using `mv` (bad mistake!)

The new directory structure is: `~/GitOpenSourceApps/chatgpt-custom-data/chatgpt-retrieval` (2)

Now I didn't know that the `pip` files inside virtual environment `chatgpt-retrieval` is correspond to the old directory structure (1).

If the current directory structure, which is (2), is different from when it's initialized, which is (1), by running `pip install <packages>`, `pip` will automatically without warning, **install directly into global environment**. This global environment is `python3 -m site --user-site` or `~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`.

Now my global environment is messed up with newly installed packages. How do I remove all of the installed packages **and their dependencies safely**? Simply running `pip uninstall` won't remove the dependencies!

Since I have installed some 3rd party apps like Vosk, Howdy, ... that are also used Python and they are the only apps that I allowed their packages to be installed inside global environment and I don't want to remove something mistakenly.

I've tried to use `pipdeptree` to analyze but the entanglement is too much. I've searched if there is a way to know which program use which packages but no use.

Comment: I know now, I can delete the __pycache__ files in some packages and then wait if they recompiled or not